# Raspberry Pi would not boot

Tags: boot, debian

I just successfully installed a rapberry debian provided by NOOBS and the installation process
went quite smoothly. But after it has been installed, I cannot boot the Pi again.

The green light will flash once when the power is on, and I can see the lauching screen but afterwards, there is a whole black screen meanwhile the green light is off and the only thing still on is the red light.

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, when there is only red light, it means bad SD card, not valid /boot partition. Try to copy it again or try with Raspbian.

Comment: I finally managed to boot by switching to a smaller SD card.

Previously I tried two 16GB Sandisk but they are not working, so I picked a 8GB Sandisk and boom! It works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I changed to a 8GiB SD card instead of the 16GiB card I had before, and it worked. It was probably just a bad card for the Pi.